# should I block 9000 port when I using php-fpm?

Tags: php, security, firewall

Should I block 9000 port when I using php-fpm?

I want to know that when I open a port 9000 and run php-fpm,
can the attacker execute specific file by request my server using port number 9000.

Comment: Port 9000 should be closed for incoming connections in your firewall. There's no reason to allow external requests to PHP-FPM directly.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks you. Did you mean that it is possible to execute external php file by attacker using 9000 port on my server?

Comment: You shouldn't have more ports open than necessary. Basically, block all ports except the ones the application needs to work (like port 80/443 for the web server for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can conf it with

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

to only allow it been accessed from localhost

And check it

```
$ netstat -tlnp | grep 9000
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

Answer (score -1):

I changed the 9000 PHP-FPM port because they put me a malware because of the default port. So it's better you change the 9000 port to another for PHP-FPM

Comment: As you said, someone can access your FPM port. Hence you should block inbound traffic on your FPM port so that no one can access your FPM server.

Comment: Changing port wouldn't secure your server if you keep it open to public. You have to configure it to listen ONLY to 127.0.0.1